Why do objects slow down when they hit the ground?
Say you drop an object on the ground. For the purpose of this question, I am just focusing on the slowing down of the object, not if it rebounds. I was just wondering which of the two reasons explains an object slowing down when it hits the ground:

The object transfers kinetic energy to the ground, losing energy as it does so.
The ground exerts an upward force on the object when the object hits it, providing "negative work" and slowing it down


Do you mean why objects slow down when they bounce off the ground (i.e. when they rebound)? You also say you are not focusing on the rebound, however.

You need to be much clearer on what it is you want us to explain when you say "I am just focusing on the slowing down of the object, not if it rebounds." Are you trying to get us to consider the object before it comes to a stop (and thus before it rebounds) or what other possible thing you want us to consider?

Your question is focusing on the wrong conserved quantity. The general answer to “why do objects slow down when they hit the ground” is about the transfer of momentum, not the transfer of energy.
The falling object has a downward momentum. The ground exerts an upwards force. This leads to a reduction in the magnitude of the momentum and therefore a reduction in the speed.
The momentum explanation holds in all cases of dropping things on the ground. In contrast your energy explanation 1 almost never holds (the ground almost never gains KE), and explanation 2 holds only when the ground is soft and deformable.

Why does the ground have to be deformable for the second explanation to hold true?

@user386598 the work done by a force is $W=\vec F \cdot \vec d$ where $\vec d$ is the displacement of the material at the point of application of $\vec F$. If the ground is not deformable then $\vec d=0$ so $W=0$

#2 is true.
Kinetic energy transfer to the ground is negligible because the earth is so much heavier than the dropped object.
As far as the dropped object is concerned, the ground is immovable. All the kinetic energy of the dropped object goes into deforming it in the course of decelerating it.
Once its kinetic energy is zero, the elasticity of the deformed object then causes it to rebound. If the energy loss during the deformation is zero, then the dropped object bounces off the earth with the same velocity with which it originally struck the ground.

In the case of an object hitting another object though, such as a marble hitting another marble, would 1 hold true because kinetic energy is transferred?

@user386598, in a perfectly head-on collision, the kinetic energy is converted into potential energy which then gives rise to a bounce. one marble stops dead and the other one proceeds.

What does the term "gives rise to a bounce mean?" This is probably a basic question, but I am just starting high school so I don't understand many concepts.
